# Get all arguments passed to a class in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it generally possible to obtain all arguments/constructor parameters given to a class?

Something like:

```
trait GetMyArgs {
    def myArgs = ???
}

class Foo(i: Int, d: Double) extends GetMyArgs
```

=>

```
scala> val f = new Foo(5, 6.6)
scala> f.myArgs
(5, 6.6) // or similar
```

Comment: What is that you are trying to do? using reflection is generally discouraged

Comment: have a look at http://scalameta.org/

Comment: Thanks, @daydreamer I'm essentially doing a form of memoization, there's a nice way to do this by implementing a function as a map, but this has the nice property of being able to mix in memorization to an existing function.

Comment: And of course, can be used to "memoize" a class creation instead of just a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def myArgs = {
    this.getClass.getDeclaredFields
      .toList
      .map(i => {
        i.setAccessible(true)
        i.getName -> i.get(this)
      }).toMap
  }
```

You can just use **java** `reflection` to do this. but need to call out, if the variable not use and the constructor param is not `val`, the `myArgs` will output **empty** `Map`.

Comment: Thanks! It's actually a good property to not include variables that are not used or stored as members in my case. What I was looking for is essentially a "fingerprint" for a particular instance of a constructed class, so if some variable is different but the class is the same, they should have the same fingerprint.

Comment: I should also note that yes this is essentially what the `hashCode` function does for a case class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is same example as above, but in sorted form :)

```
def myArgs: List[(String, AnyRef)] = {
    this.getClass.getDeclaredFields.toList
      .map(i => {
        i.setAccessible(true)
        i.getName -> i.get(this)
      })
  }
```